# RVM - Ruby update - Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm, passenger

I'm trying to update the ruby version on one of my servers. I've updated the RVM and installed the new Ruby but I have a problem with passenger (standalone).

As far as I can see it was installed as a gem from Gemfile before (Ruby 2.2.5).

```
bundle exec gem list passenger
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
passenger (5.0.30)
```

And it is still installed as a gem from Gemfile (in Ruby 2.6.3):

```
bundle exec gem list passenger
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
passenger (5.0.30)
```

Ruby in my rvm is set as default `rvm --default use 2.6.3`

I'm not using any gemset names (there is the default one @global).

When I try to deploy the application with this config i ran into error when the capistrano is trying to stop the passenger:

```
00:34 deploy:restart
  01 ~/.rvm/bin/rvm 2.6.3@global do bundle exec passenger stop
  01 Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.
  01
  01 Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

But as you can see I did not use any sudo or rvmsudo...

When I enter the server and try to restart the passenger manually I get the same error:

```
bundle exec passenger stop --help --verbose
Unable to autodetect the currently active RVM gem set name. This could happen if you ran this program using 'sudo' instead of 'rvmsudo'. When using RVM, you're always supposed to use 'rvmsudo' instead of 'sudo!'.

Please try rerunning this program using 'rvmsudo'. If that doesn't help, please contact this program's author for support.
```

Any idea how can I 'make it work' ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like updating passenger to newer version did help (it updated to 6.0.2).

Comment: Thanks a lot! The funny thing is that on an old server it was just showing the error message but started Passenger anyway. It's the same app on the new server with the same Ruby/Rails version, and same versions of all gems, the only difference is that the new sever have Ubuntu 18.04, the old have 12.04. Strange. I changed in Gemfile to `passenger '~> 6.0.4'`, with Rails 4.2.2. Works on both the old and new server.